# Running winscp on a mac using wine

Tags: mac, wine, winscp

I have a Mac (El Capitan OS) and I really want to use `winscp` on it.

I installed wine on my Mac using:

```
brew install wine
```

It installed:

```
https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/wine-3.0_2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
```

I then downloaded the latest `winscp` installer: `WinSCP-5.13.2-Setup.exe` and tried:

```
wine WinSCP-5.13.2-Setup.exe
```

And I'm getting these errors:

```
004b:err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out
004b:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
004b:fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
004d:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
004d:fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
004d:fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
004d:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (0x2008a): stub
004d:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonCreate (0x2008a, L"Installing"): stub
004d:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (0x2008a): stub
004d:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonCreate (0x2008a, L"Installing WinSCP."): stub
004d:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x2007c c05a 1 0x0
004d:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x3007c c05a 1 0x0
004d:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x30074 c05a 1 0x0
004d:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x40074 c05a 1 0x0
004d:fixme:shell:SHAutoComplete stub
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable 0: stub!
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {2087c2f4-2cef-4953-a8ab-66779b670495} not registered
004d:err:ole:create_server class {2087c2f4-2cef-4953-a8ab-66779b670495} not registered
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {2087c2f4-2cef-4953-a8ab-66779b670495} could be created for context 0x5
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200d6 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200e0 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200e0 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x400fe enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x400fe enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200e0 enable 0: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200e0 enable -1: stub!
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200de enable 0: stub!
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090} not registered
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090} could be created for context 0x1
004d:fixme:sfc:SfcIsFileProtected (0x0, L"c:\\Program Files\\WinSCP\\unins001.exe") stub
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
004d:err:ole:create_server class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} could be created for context 0x5
004d:fixme:progress:ProgressWindowProc state 0002 not yet handled
004d:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 0x200de enable -1: stub!
```

Then it pops up the installer dialog box which eventually throws an error box saying `OLE error 80040154 classID: {00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've download [winebottler for mac](https://wiki.winehq.org/Third_Party_Applications) from the official page. It converts a windows app into mac app, Now the program is running but I still have problems with shell when i use SCP as a protocol(Shell is not running), but using FTP it seems working fine.

If I found a solution for that I'll updated my current post